# Choosing 2 random items from 2 lists, 1 of each, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have 2 lists, let's say
fruits = [Banana, Apple, Orange]
names = [Dan, Guy, May].

I want to randomly choose 1 item frim each list,
possible return will be - Banana, May

I've see answers like:
random. Sample(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 2)
But they all refers to picking 2 items from 1 list,
or picking 1 item from multiple lists.
thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something or why don't you just sample one item from one list first and then sample one item from the other list?

Comment: Make a random selection of one item from one list, then from the other. What is the problem with that?

Comment: Hi, the way to flag something as solved is to select the appropriate answer at the "accepted" one. Not to edit the title of the question as you have done here.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```py
return random.choice(fruits), random.choice(names)
```

If you need to cover more than two lists:

```py
lists = [fruits, names, etc]
return tuple(random.choice(l) for l in lists)
```